# OAuth v.s my custom token based implementation

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I am writing backend for a mobile app where the login info (user), details of the app and everything used in the mobile app will be on the server side.

That's how I have written the app flow:

- The created users are saved on the server side via registration API
- The newly created users send credentials and after authentication, I generate a dynamic token which is shared with the user for rest of the API calls
- For every other call that a user makes, the token is authenticated and then the response is generated.
- Each login generates a new token so at a time the same user won't be able to use the same account on 2 different mobiles. Since on valid login, a new token will be generated for API usage.

Whole of the communication takes place over SSL so everything is already encrypted. I want to know the security threats that would be saved by OUATH 2 in this scenario.

**P.S** Please write your thoughts in comments if you down-vote this question. Will highly appreciate it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you develop a custom solution instead of going directly with oauth?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The custom solution is simple, even looks simpler to me than auth2 or maybe because I am not that familiar wiht oauth2. Instead of passing user credentials, we just pass token. That's it.

Comment: I can suggest to read a nice answer about why you shouldn't create your own solution: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: OAuth 2.0 doesn't necessarily add security. It provide a framework for access delegation. In simple words, OAuth 2.0 define how a user can grant permission to a client (application) to access a resource owned by user. Compare that with your solution. I bet in future you will have trouble with support than security concerns. That's why it's advisable to use exiting protocols over custom ones.

Comment: Thanks @KavinduDodanduwa as far as the support is concerned, it is not expected to increase. I will definitely move to OAuth later on as soon as I get time.